# Why does a google font load differently on safari than chrome, and how do I fix it?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Chrome and Safari both load the same font in different manners, and it's very annoying, is there a way to fix it?[image]

They aren't big differences, in some cases, but in others, like with my main content it's very big.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is absolutely normal and you can't really "fix it". Every client has his own specificity and you hardly have the same render in every browser (this why front dev have nor more hair).
Eventually if you want you can do specific css for each browser with [conditional](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/) rules such as

```
[if IE] .box {  
   font-weight: 900;
}
```

For ie in example of course.

For chrome you can use :

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 

body {...}
.class {...}

}
```

Careful tough this will affect Safari, Epiphany...